# Can someone explain these few lines of python code file name __init__.py

Tags: python

```
import os, unittest

# figure all the modules available
dir = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
```

This prints the current directory, as **file** points points to the current file name

```
mods = {}
```

dont know what this does, but i can guess this creates a list ? or an array ?

```
l = []
```

I guess this also creates an array and assigns it l

```
__all__ = []
```

Dont know if `__all__` has some special significance, but it does look like an array

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if not file.endswith('.py') or file == '__init__.py':
        continue
    name = file[5:-3]
```

5:-3 , what does that mean ?

```
mods[name] = __import__(file[:-3], globals(), locals(), [])
```

what does mods means ?

```
__all__.append(name)
l.append(mods[name].suite())

def suite():
    return unittest.TestSuite(l)
```

Comment: I suggest you begin with a [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), as *"explain every line of this program"* is not really a question

Comment: It "figures all the modules available", imports each module, gets it's unittest suite and finally defines a method that runs all (sub)suites together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is creating a test suite out of the `suite()` functions defined in the files in the same directory with a `.py` extension.

The `[5:-3]` is ignoring the first five characters of the file names (which I assume to be *test*_), and the `.py` extension.

__all__ is a list with the identifiers that a module exports. It's being set to the list of the modules previously recovered.

This convoluted code is probably the wrong way to achieve what's intended.

Comment: [5:-3] ... **FIVE** ... `test_`

Comment: @John Machin. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly, he's listing the files in the directory which end with .py, then adds those names to the content listing of the of the package ([`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)). He goes on the import those scripts by name (using [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)), then makes that list of modules (objects representing scripts) into a group of unit-tests ([unittest.TestSuite](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite)).

You will save yourself a world of hurt by reading (or at least skim!) the official tutorial in full:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

---

To answer your direct questions:

`__all__` is a way to list the contents of your package, if you don't like the way python does it by default. Documentation here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

The index `[5:-3]` means take the items from the list starting at index 5 and up to (but not including) -3. Negative indexes count from the end, ie -1 is the last item. Documentation here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

`mods` was created earlier in the script. It's a dict (perl users read "hash") with no special significance. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of your questions are surrounding basic Python Syntax.

{} sets a dictionary which is like an associative array
[] is a list, which is like a mutable standard array

```
for file in os.listdir(dir): if not file.endswith('.py') or file == 'init.py': continue name = file[5:-3]
```

Loops through files, I'm pretty sure it is ignoring non python files or init.py and then gets the a substring of the file name

[5:-3] essentially get a substring of the file name, though I am not 100% sure if that is different when using os package to loop through directories.

mods is the dictionary declared above `mods = {}`

the append stuff is adding things to the lists declared with []

You should read "Dive Into Python". Or at least go onto python's site and read the part about basic data structures.